# Weird Angular ng-model issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model

I have a weird question regarding my Angular app.

I wanted to get the input texts when user enter texts in the input box.

my html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="texts" ng-change="type()"/>
```

my js

```
  $scope.type = function() {
      console.log($scope.texts)
      console.log($scope) //doesn't see texts property either
  }
```

However, every time I type something, the first console log shows 'undefined'. It's like controller can't find the texts property. Can anyone help me this weird issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you then define it first?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Inside a function defined on `$scope` you can usually find the values you're looking for on `this` instead. So, try replacing `$scope.texts` with `this.texts`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Angular provides two-way binding, so why would you use a function for this?

Comment: Your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/spencerooni/mX37Q/ - We can only guess about the code haven't shown though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using angular's [two-way data binding system](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding):

> Data-binding in Angular apps is the automatic synchronization of data
>   between the model and view components. The way that Angular implements
>   data-binding lets you treat the model as the single-source-of-truth in
>   your application. The view is a projection of the model at all times.
>   **When the model changes, the view reflects the change, and vice versa.**

This allows us to synchronize the properties of our controller's scope by binding to them in our html.

So, we might define our controller like this:

```
myApp.controller('SomeController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.text = "";
});
```

Now, we can use this in our html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="text" />
</div>
```

The important thing to notice here is the `ng-model` directive. Here we bind the `text` property we defined in our controller to the `<input>` field. Now, with two-way binding, if we type into the input field it will automatically update the `text` property. This way we can access the value of the input field within our controller without having to do any extra work.

Here is a plnkr with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xEkoDbPxwrWgGfuEiS3a?p=preview

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` has to be passed in to the controller. Check your controller arguments.